# Xcode: Не работает performSegue withIdentifier

Tags: xcode, swift, swift3

[image: Мои ViewController`ы]

Перехожу по нажатию любой кнопки на GameViewController, там по тайтлу кнопки определяю уровень и загружаю его:

```
let sceneView = GameScene(fileNamed: "Level " + String(buttonTitle))
let skView = SKView(frame: self.view.frame)
self.view.addSubview(skView)
skView.showsFPS = true
skView.showsNodeCount = true
skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
sceneView!.scaleMode = .aspectFill
skView.presentScene(sceneView)
```

И потом спокойно могу перейти в главное меню при помощи Segue:

```
if node.name == "menu"{
   self.viewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToMainMenu", sender: self)
   self.removeAllActions()
   self.removeAllChildren()
}
```

Но если зайти на любую сцену (любой уровень) и обновить этот уровень при помощи кнопки retry:

```
if node.name == "retry" {
   let currentScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "Level "+String(thisScene))
   let transition = SKTransition.doorsCloseHorizontal(withDuration: 0.5)
   currentScene!.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFill
   self.scene!.view?.presentScene(currentScene!, transition: transition)
}
```

То

```
if node.name == "menu"{
   self.viewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToMainMenu", sender: self)
   self.removeAllActions()
   self.removeAllChildren()
}
```

**Перестает работать**

Не пойму в чем дело.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При обновление/переходу назад/переходу вперед нужно инициализировать ViewController:

```
if node.name == "retry"{
    print("retry")
    let currentScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "Level "+String(thisScene))
    let transition = SKTransition.doorsCloseHorizontal(withDuration: 0.5)
    currentScene!.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFill
    currentScene?.viewController = self.viewController
    self.scene!.view?.presentScene(currentScene!, transition: transition)
}
```

И тд

Переход в меню:

```
if node.name == "menu"{
   self.viewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToMainMenu", sender: self)
   self.scene!.removeFromParent()
   self.scene!.view?.removeFromSuperview()

   self.removeFromParent()
   self.removeAllActions()
   self.removeAllChildren()          
}
```